# how to concatenate a series of fields of type bit (1) only when its value is 1?

Tags: mysql

Having the `requests` table with a series of bit(1) type fields that correspond to a series of possible requirements in a request

```
CREATE TABLE requests (
  `id` int,
  `classroom` varchar(255),
  `speaker` bit(1),
  `datashow` bit(1),
  `wifi` bit(1),
  `pointer` bit(1)
);
```

It is possible to concatenate speaker, datashow, wifi and pointer fields when its value is 1?

So having the following dataset

```
insert into requests
  (`id`, `classroom`, `speaker`, `datashow`, `wifi`, `pointer`)
values
  (1, 'A101', true, false, false, false),
  (2, 'A102', true, true, false, false),
  (3, 'A103', true, false, true, false),
  (4, 'A104', false, false, false, false),
  (5, 'A101', false, false, false, true)
```

Is it possible to obtain a result similar to the following?

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| id | classroom | requirements       |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1 | A101      | speaker            |
|  2 | A102      | speaker datashow   |
|  3 | A103      | speaker wifi       |
|  4 | A104      |                    |
|  5 | A101      | pointer            |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
```

At the moment I am trying `concat` with a series of `case when` but without success

```
select
  id,
  classroom,
  concat (
    (case when speaker = 1 then 'speaker ' end),
    (case when datashow = 1 then 'datashow ' end),
    (case when wifi = 1 then 'wifi ' end),
    (case when pointer = 1 then 'pointer' end)
  ) requirements
from
  requests
```

I add this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92e5a2/1) to facilitate your collaboration

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for making it notice, question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select
  id,
  classroom,
  concat (
    (case when speaker = 1 then 'speaker ' else '' end),
    (case when datashow = 1 then 'datashow ' else '' end),
    (case when wifi = 1 then 'wifi ' else '' end),
    (case when pointer = 1 then 'pointer' else '' end)
  ) requirements
from
  requests
```

your cases return null, and concatenate with null also return null

Comment: Thank you for answering, you are right, I overlooked it.

Comment: This works, but would leave a trailing space at the end of every non empty entry in the `requirements` column.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CONCAT_WS` here.  This functions will ignore `NULL` components, and will only a space separator between two entries, but not at the end.

```
SELECT
    id,
    classroom,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', CASE WHEN speaker THEN 'speaker' END,
              CASE WHEN datashow THEN 'datashow' END,
              CASE WHEN wifi     THEN 'wifi' END,
              CASE WHEN pointer  THEN 'pointer' END) AS requirements
FROM requests
ORDER BY id;
```

[image]

### Demo